# Getting ROC curve with one point

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, roc

I'm trying to build ROC curve for XGB model outputs.
I'm getting tpr & fpr arrays with 3 values only, which eventually outputs ROC curve with one point only:

```
X = data_db.copy().drop(columns=['Y'])
y = data_db.copy()['Y'] 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=20)
# XGBoost model 
model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# make predictions for test data
y_predict = model.predict(X_test)

fpr, tpr, thresholds =roc_curve(y_test,y_predict)
tpr
```

the output is:

```
array([0.        , 0.98551517, 1.        ])
```

and the ROC curve looks like
[image]

why I'm not getting ROC curve with more than one point?

Comment: What is the shape of your data, i.e. what is the length of X_test?

Comment: 7350 rows × 1886 columns

Answer (score 1):

For my ROC curves I use yellowbrick. You could try something like this:

```py
from yellowbrick.classifier import ROCAUC

X = data_db.copy().drop(columns=['Y'])
y = data_db.copy()['Y'] 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=20)

# XGBoost model 
model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# make predictions for test data
y_predict = model.predict(X_test)

# create the visualizer and fit training data
visualizer = ROCAUC(model, classes=["Y"])
visualizer.fit(X_train, y_train)

# add the score to the visualizer using test data
visualizer.score(X_test, y_test)

# display ROC curve    
visualizer.show()
```

Note that `classes = []` could be used to name multiple classes if you're working on a multi-classification model.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you don't need to use actual column names in `classes = []`. You could change Y for whatever value you'd like to appear on the legend.